# Getting incorrect data in datatime from varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

In database a table called Tbl_GIT. The data are inserting / Updating from multiple places. I get some data that format is like `01/02/18 01:53:30 p. m.` and `01/02/18 08:22:24 a. m.` for temporary i want that if the data are inserting/ Updating in this format i can correct this using trigger after insert /Update.  Filed GT9 and GT10 are varchar(50) in table. So how can i do this.

Below is my sample data

```
ID            GT9                    GT10
 7686004401    12/8/17 4:33:36 PM     01/02/18 06:51:38 a. m. 
 6871761806    12/7/17 5:45:29 AM     01/02/18 12:03:33 p. m. 
 7694553943    12/21/17 7:22:59 AM    01/02/18 07:45:57 a. m.  
 7696265108    12/29/17 6:55:53 AM    01/02/18 12:38:24 PM
 696265124     12/28/17 8:19:30 PM    01/02/18 08:56:21 AM
 697024242     12/29/17 9:35:44 AM    01/02/18 05:25:28 AM
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Table DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_GIT] (
    [ORDERID]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [ID]             INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GT1]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT2]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT3]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT4]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT5]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT6]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT7]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT8]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT9]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GT10]       VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [GPSLONG]        VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
    [GPSLAT]         VARCHAR (20)  NULL   

);
```

Comment: if you want a trigger, we'll need your table's DDL please. I'm going to **assume** that you have other columns like GT1, GT2, ...GT8 or others that have the same problem as well. If so, have you also considered using 3NF aswell?

Comment: @Larnu yes there is GT1 To GT11 but i was provide GT9, GT11 above. Because all other are storing notes so that is not important for me

Comment: Can any of those columns could have the bad formatting? Also, again, what is your reasoning for not using 3NF? Is this also an option?

Comment: @Larnu no there is not any bad formation of data in those fields

Comment: @Larnu 3NF are you talking about normalization. Sorry i can't do that right know there are 1 TB of data in the database

Comment: So it's just `GT10` that has the problem? And yes, 3NF = 3rd normal Form. I still need that DLL though.

Comment: @Larnu i have updated question with table DDL. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Below sample code should update the varchar field GT10 to the required format.

```
create table Tbl_GIT
(
ID int identity,
GT9 varchar(50),
GT10 varchar(50)
)
GO
insert into Tbl_GIT values ('12/8/17 4:33:36 PM','01/02/18 06:51:38 a. m.'),('12/29/17 6:55:53 AM','01/02/18 12:38:24 PM')

select * from Tbl_GIT
GO
create trigger tr_tmp_Insert on Tbl_GIT after insert
as
begin
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE GT10 LIKE '%p. m.' OR GT10 LIKE '%p.m.' OR GT10 LIKE '%a. m.' OR GT10 LIKE '%a.m.')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Tbl_GIT SET GT10 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GT10,'p.m.','PM'),'p. m.','PM'),'a.m.','AM'),'a. m.','AM')
    END
end
GO
insert into Tbl_GIT values ('12/8/17 4:33:36 PM','01/05/18 06:51:38 p. m.')
insert into Tbl_GIT values ('12/29/17 6:55:53 AM','01/12/18 12:38:24 a. m.')
insert into Tbl_GIT values ('12/29/17 6:55:53 AM','01/01/18 12:38:24 a.m.')
insert into Tbl_GIT values ('12/29/17 6:55:53 AM','01/03/18 12:38:24 p.m.')
select * from Tbl_GIT
```